# How to keep track of attempts in a JavaScript number guessing game?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm trying to keep track of how many guesses are made and then print that number when the correct number is guessed. The number of guesses isn't being updated when the wrong number is guessed, so it keeps showing up that it took only 1 guess, when it really took more.

```
let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

console.log(num);

let num_guess = 0

function do_guess() {
    let guess = Number(document.getElementById("guess").value);
    let num_guess = 1

    let message = document.getElementById("message");

    if (isNaN(guess)) {
        message.innerHTML = 'That is not a number!';
    }
    else if (guess > 20) {
        message.innerHTML = 'That number is not in range, try again.'
        num_guess+=;
    }
    else if (guess > num) {
        message.innerHTML = "No, try a lower number."
        num_guess+=;
    }
    else if (guess < num) {
        message.innerHTML = "No, try a higher number."
        num_guess+=;
    }
    else if (guess == num) {
        message.innerHTML = "You got it! It took you " + num_guess + " tries.";
    }
}
```

<!doctype html>

```
<head>
    <title>Higher - Lower</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Higher Lower</h1>
        <p>Guess a number between 1 and a maximum number of your choosing!</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Your guess:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="guess" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="do_guess()">Guess</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p id="message"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="higherlower.js"></script>
</body>
```

```

Comment: You have created the variable num_guess twice. Remove let num_guess = 1 from the do_guess function if you want it to be global and not scoped to the function.

Comment: It looks like on the second line of do_guess() you are resetting ‘num_guess’ to 1 with every guess. You probably want to remove that line and make sure do_guess gets called every time a guess is made

Comment: You are re-defining the variable inside the scope, so each time the function fires, it resets to 1.

Answer (score 1):

`let num_guess = 1`
You are declaring the variable twice and each time the function is called, it will be set to 1.

`num_guess+=;` this won't increment the variable. See below.

```
let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

console.log(num);

let num_guess = 0;

function do_guess() {
    let guess = Number(document.getElementById("guess").value);

    let message = document.getElementById("message");

    if (isNaN(guess)) {
        message.innerHTML = 'That is not a number!';
    }
    else if (guess > 20) {
        message.innerHTML = 'That number is not in range, try again.'
        num_guess += 1;
    }
    else if (guess > num) {
        message.innerHTML = "No, try a lower number."
        num_guess += 1;
    }
    else if (guess < num) {
        message.innerHTML = "No, try a higher number."
        num_guess += 1;
    }
    else if (guess == num) {
        message.innerHTML = "You got it! It took you " + num_guess + " tries.";
        num_guess += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been staring at it for a while but completely missed where I declared the variable above the function.

Comment: I just changed my answer. Hope it helps.